# cakephp 3.0 'App\Controller\ContactForm' not found modelless form

Tags: forms, cakephp-3.0, contact-form

I am trying to create a modelless form using cakePHP 3.0, I have been following the guide through the cookbook here http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html but it seems I am getting confused as to where to put ContactForm.php. It says to put it in src/Form/ContactForm.php but it did not work. Can someone direct me to this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pls, provide a bit more info about your problem
1) is ContactForm recognized in controller?
if not - check namespace
2) handle your data only in

```
protected function _execute(array $data)
{
    // Send an email.
    return true;
}
```

not in controller's

```
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($contact->execute($this->request->data)) {
           //NOT HERE!!!
        } else {
           // error
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also bear in mind that your server configuration may forbid php short open tags.

Make sure your class starts with `<?php` and not only `<?` to be on the safer side. If not, CakePHP will simply respond by the Your\Namespace\Class Not Found message.

Answer (score 0):

Just verify where you have put `Form` Folder, it must be inside `src` Folder.
Also be sure that the class has `Form` as suffix.

Because your error is `App\Controller\ContactForm not found`, that means that you have NOT put `Form` Folder inside `src` Folder.